# How to show/hide the same blocks inside similar blocks with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code as follows:

```
<div class="mama">
    <div class="son">Item 1</div>
</div>
<div class="mama">
    <div class="son">Item 2</div>
</div>

$(".mama").hover(
    function() {
        $(".son").show();
    },
    function() {
        $(".son").hide();
    }
);
```

Forward to help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you include some context/existing code? Your question doesn't make sense without it really...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`hover()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) event and just scope your actions to the relevant elements:

```
$("div.mama").hover(function() {
  $(this).find("div.son").show();
}, function() {
  $(this).find("div.son").hide();
});
```

There are many variations on how you can limit this to only children of the affected element.

Comment: How this very positive and easy to understand. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to only hide the ".son" blocks inside each ".mama" block, then it'd be something like this:

```
$('.mama').each(function() {
  var mama = $(this);
  mama.hover(
    function() { mama.find('.son').show(); },
    function() { mama.find('.son').hide(); }
  );
});
```

Comment: There's no need for the added complexity of this. See my answer.

Comment: If we do like this: 
... $('.mama') ...
is only the first block is in effect. We have to do like this:
... $("div.mama") ...
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

if all you're doing is showing or hiding content, you don't need jQuery. CSS already has this functionality

```
 .mama .son {
      display:none;
 }

 .mama:hover .son {
      display:block;
 }
```

Comment: IE6 doesn't support :hover on non-anchors.

Comment: I just give a simple example to other complex problems using JQuery. Thanks!